# Seeking advice on code used to dynamically import functions from external '.py' files

Tags: python, dynamic, import, eval

I have a fairly extensive coding background in multiple environments, but, am new to Python.  I thought I had figured out a way to import functions dynamically from an external '.py' file, but am unsure if it is the best way.  I found problems with using `importlib.import_module()` and `importlib.__import__` based on my goal.  Is there another way to accomplish what I am doing here?  Effectively, I am wanting to have the same result as I would get when using `from x import y` where x and y are variables.  I thought I would be able to use `eval('from '+x+' import '+y)` but this throws a syntax error.

I was hoping to accomplish this by contriving a dictionary with files as the keys (i.e., a file named 'file1.py' would create a key of 'file1') and a list of the desired functions as a list associated with its relative key.  This can easily be built either literally, or by reading a path for file names and then using the dir() function to get a list of the functions in each individual file (among many other ways).  Next, I hoped to simply use nested `for` loops to walk the dictionary keys and their associated key value lists and used `eval('from '+key+' import '+currentListItem)`.  Unfortunately, this throws a syntax error on the execution of the generated 'from...import...' statement.  See below for example code.  My problems with importlib (and getattr) is that I am unable to maintain the 'abstraction' provided by this method as I have to define a 'handle' in order to use importlib (i.e., `handle = getattr(...)` or `handle = importlib.import_module(key)` meaning that I basically have to hard code a 'handle name' for the given module being imported and thus may just as well hard code the 'from file_name import function' statements).

````py
# simplistic example of what I was thinking....
# FILE file.py contains the code...
def asub(p1, p2 = None, p3 = None):
    print(p1, p2 if p2 else 'p2 defaulted', p3 if p3 else 'p3 defaulted')
    return

# FILE b.py contains the code...

#!/usr/local/bin/python3
subs = {'file':['asub']}
for key in subs:
    for subrt in subs[key]:
        print("==>", key, subrt)
        eval('from '+key+' import '+subrt)

# on execution of b.py (i.e., ```python3 b.py``` I get the following...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 9, in <module>
    eval('from '+key+' import '+subrt)
  File "<string>", line 1
    from file import asub
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
````

NOTE: I understand that this may not be the greatest thing for importing modules/functions as it tends to 'hide' the information that you would need for documentation and usage of the imported functions.

However, I am sure that there will be instances where this may be useful or where similar methodology may be useful in a case other than importing.

As I said, I am new to Python, so, am looking for feedback/guidance on this in a (cringe) 'Pythonic' sense.

One other thing: I get that eval() can open the door for code insertion but for the above specific use, and given that the files containing the functions are well locked down, I think it should be plenty safe (?)...

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Comment: What sort of problems did you run with `importlib`? `importlib` is the way to go. You're calling eval, which is always slightly wonky, but since you do only import it should be fine. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path , which probably does what you want.

Comment: problem with importlib was that I could not keep the different functions 'abstracted' and then simply use them by name.  i.e., I was not able to get it to work will keeping the abstraction/dynamics offered by the variable method I am using as I had to do something like ```handle = importlib.import_module(key)``` (only one for loop needed here) and then I had to use ```handle.f1()``` to use the desired function.  Which wouldn't work for many different files/functions as a group.

Comment: You can also use `f1 = getattr(handle, 'f1')` or `f1 = handle.f1`

Comment: Thanks Radoslaw, I looked at that also, but, if I do that I still have to hard code 'f1' which, again, removes the abstraction/dynamics provided by the discovery and variablization of the references.  Is there some way to get the same effect as ```from file import function``` where 'file' and 'function' are variables using importlib?  Since the importing will be completely variable based on the 'list' defining what to import, then you won't be able to define a useful 'handle' in an abstract way.  Which means you might as well just hard code the imports.

Comment: Apologies Radoslaw, the eval(from...import...) is not working after all....
'''
  File "b.py", line 9, in <module>
    eval('from '+key+' import '+subrt)
  File "<string>", line 1
    from a import asub'''

so, back to square 1

Comment: Trivially, `eval` is for **expressions** and `exec` is for **statements** including all forms of `import`.  That’s not to say you should be using either here!

Comment: OP here, and trivially, 'exec' worked.  Thank you very much Davis.  Can you offer a suggestion on how I may approach this using importlib or another method and yet still maintain the ability to keep it 'dynamic'?  As I stated in the post, if I have to define a correlated handle for each import, then that removes the dynamic aspect of this method.  Thanks, again...

Comment: Why do you care about having a named “handle” for the module?  That’s no different from having a variable for a list being searched or a file being read.  Also: do you plan to use the imported things by explicit name (implying that the selection is a set fixed when you write the code) or will you select among them with strings (for example, looking up items based on user input)?

Comment: Hi Davis, this started as an educational exercise and the reason for not wanting to 'name' a handle is that I can't do that dynamically in correlation with dynamic imports.  The idea here is that I would like to simply 'construct' a list of things to import (perhaps a common set of functions for scripts) and be able to refer to the imported functions easily without hard coding for each one.  How I 'derive' the list of things to be imported may vary.  For instance, I may read a directory for the .py files that contain the functions to be imported and iteratively do ```from filevar import *```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

subs = {'file':['asub']}

for key in subs:
    # import module by file path
    # since path is relative, it will import against working directory
    mod = SourceFileLoader("", "%s.py" % key).load_module()

    for subrt in subs[key]:
        print("==>", key, subrt)

        # retrieve object from module by name subrt
        obj = getattr(mod, subrt)

        # this should call file.asub and it does
        obj('1', '2')

        # this add local variable with the same name
        locals()[subrt] = obj

# so now we can call asub as if it were done
# from file import asub
asub('3', '4')
```

This code prints:

```
==> file asub
1 2 p3 defaulted
3 4 p3 defaulted
```

This works on my python3 and requires python 3.3 at least. This is built on top of question [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path). `locals()[subrt] = obj` puts imported object into local variables directory, which allows calling to it as if it were done `from file import asub`. If i understood correctly this is what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Thank you sir, that definitely helps.  It was the 'locals()' variable setting that I think I was missing.  Was unaware of that. And the deeper view into Python was just what I was hoping for with this.  Your time and effort is much appreciated.  I up voted this answer, but, I apparently do not have enough reputation points for it to be published, but, I have accepted it as 'the answer'.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Final form based on accepted answer provided by Radoslaw.  NOTE: I also tested with importlib.import_module(key) as well and that worked the same way except that you may have to use sys.path.insert(...) to make sure your module can be located.

```py
import os, sys, re
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

# Build list of 'things' to be imported
#   (presumably via a lookup of some sort)
# I hard coded it here as a simple dictionary element for testing/dev.
# Notice that a fully qualified file name is used so that the target
#   subroutine/function can come from any specified/discovered file
# Another option may be to use only a list of file names here and then # use 'dir()' to get the functions from the file and then choose from
# the the list returned.  This is illustrated below.
subs = {'/some/fully/qualified/path/file.txt':['asub']}

# import the files
for key in subs:
    mod = SourceFileLoader("", key).load_module()

# Example of how to 'extract' the function names from the module for
# filtering and loading of explicit modules when using 'subs' as a
# list vs. a dictionary.  Here I simply excluded anything beginning
# and ending with double '_' and then processed those 'functions'.
#    for d in dir(mod):
#        if not re.match(r'^__.+?__$', d):
#            locals()[subrt] = getattr(mod, subrt)

# otherwise, if 'subs' is used as a dictionary as
# described above, just walk the list of functions
# built as part of the 'subs' dictionary
    for subrt in subs[key]:
        locals()[subrt] = getattr(mod, subrt)

# done
asub('parm1', 'p2_parm')

quit()
```

An interesting exercise.  Thanks much for the help Radoslaw.